# How to comprehand define x x and bitwise operations with it?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm using free-electrons.com to navigate in the kernel sources.
I'm wondering what is IFF_PROMISC in the following code snippet. I can see it's defined as

```
#define IFF_PROMISC                     IFF_PROMISC
```

at Linux/include/uapi/linux/if.h   and I supposed to see something similar to

```
#define IFF_PROMISC                     (unsigned long)12     //0xC
```

instead. Please explain the meaning of such define and which bits will be substituted by preprocessor above this sentence.

```
static int __dev_set_promiscuity(struct net_device *dev, int inc, bool notify)
 {
         unsigned int old_flags = dev->flags;
         kuid_t uid;
         kgid_t gid;

         ASSERT_RTNL();

         dev->flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
         dev->promiscuity += inc;
```

Comment: Provide the link please.

Comment: @2501 Here is link to the function http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/dev.c#L6008 and here is link to define http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/if.h#L114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of `IFF_PROMISC` is set in `enum net_device_flags` which is in same file  `include/uapi/linux/if.h`. It is just before the `#define` lines that you are referrring.

If you look at the file `include/uapi/linux/if.h`, you can see:

```
enum net_device_flags {
    /* */
    /* Many other values - too I removed for brevity */
    IFF_NOARP                       = 1<<7,  /* sysfs */
    IFF_PROMISC                     = 1<<8,  /* sysfs */
    IFF_ALLMULTI                    = 1<<9,  /* sysfs */
    /* Many other values - too I removed for brevity */
    /* */
};
```

And then the `#define` follows:

```
#define IFF_PROMISC                     IFF_PROMISC
```

Comment: You might want to explain why this is done that way, as OP is confused by this.

Comment: @2501 Not sure why this is done. But it shows that `IFF_PROMISC` has a numerical value associated with it like what OP was expecting.

Comment: @2501 For compatibility with glibc `net/if.h`, according to the comment above those definitions.